# Update Multiple Rows using CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

This is what I am trying to do. Basically I have some columns deliberately left blank in table `Staging_X` and to be updated later. I would like to update those columns using the `case` conditions below. I want to implement this in a stored procedure.

```
UPDATE Staging_X 
   SET Staging_X.[NoMaterial]
      (SELECT (case 
                 when ((([Up]+[Test])+[Mon])+[Down_percentage])*(1.68)=(0) 
                 then (168) else [Lost]*(1.68) 
               end) 
         FROM Staging_X)
```

Comment: If `[NoMaterial]` column always have value dependent on other columns, you should consider changing it to [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Either use a computed column, or query the table via a view that has that calculation as a column, or just make this calculation part of the insert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE Staging_X 
SET [NoMaterial] = 
    case when [Up]+[Test]+[Mon]+[Down_percentage]=0 
    then 168 else [Lost]*1.68 end
WHERE [NoMaterial] is null
```

Answer (score 3):

If I understand you correctly, you dont need a selected like that as the values are all in the same row.

So try something like

```
UPDATE  Staging_X 
SET     Staging_X.[NoMaterial] = 
        case 
            when ((([Up]+[Test])+[Mon])+[Down_percentage])*(1.68)=(0) 
                then (168) 
            else [Lost]*(1.68) 
        end
```

Answer (score 3):

more simply

```
UPDATE [Staging_X] 
    SET [NoMaterial] =
        CASE [Up]+[Test]+[Mon]+[Down_percentage]
             WHEN 0 THEN 168
             ELSE [Lost] * 1.68 
        END
```